# Android sqlite - How to manage a Integer value in where clause

Tags: android, sqlite, where-clause

I've a problem with the query to mananage the sqlite database in android.

this is a sample method :

```
public Cursor selectID( Integer id){
// query code for select
}
```

But all the query method that i see , not allow me to manage an integer parameter, or anything else except a String parameter. 
Usually i use the rawQuery method:

for example :

```
db.rawQuery("Select id from dbName where id = ?", new String[] {id});
```

But that, as i said , is not possible with Integer or other parameter ( for example

```
new Integer[] {id};
```

How i can do to solve my problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `String.valueOf(id)` which will return the String representation of your int.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(int)

So your statement will look like:

```
db.rawQuery("Select id from dbName where id = ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(id)});
```

Comment: This will not work if the column does not have numeric affinity.